# How to fetch data in a functional react JS component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, graphql

I am developing a React JS, Redux, GraphQL, TypeScript app.

And I would like to know how to invoke the function that fetches data and updates the state via GraphQL from my container.

The name of the action that loads the data via GraphQL is **appActions.getAppData();**

But it causes an infinite refresh loop because it triggers (StatusActions.startAppLoading()); which updates the state as well.

I would like to know how to fix this issue or how to rewrite /Main/index.tsx as a class component and invoke startAppLoading() from componentDidMount().

Thank you in advance.

[image: App Structure]

**main.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import { configureStore } from 'app/store';
import { Router } from 'react-router';
import { App } from './app';

// prepare store
const history = createBrowserHistory();
const store = configureStore();

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**app/index.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { App as Main } from 'app/containers/Main';
import { hot } from 'react-hot-loader';

let currentContainer = Main;

export const App = hot(module)(() => (
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={currentContainer} />
    <Route path="*">
      <Redirect to="https://google.com" />
    </Route>
  </Switch>
));
```

**app/containers/Main/index.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import style from './style.css';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useTodoActions } from 'app/actions';
import { useAppActions } from 'app/actions';
import { RootState } from 'app/reducers';
import { Header, TodoList, Footer } from 'app/components';

export namespace App {
  export interface Props extends RouteComponentProps<void> {}
}

export const App = ({ history, location }: App.Props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const appActions = useAppActions(dispatch);

const { apps } = useSelector((state: RootState) => {
    return {
      apps: state.apps
    };
  });
  appActions.getAppData();

  return (
    <div className={style.normal}>
      <Header />
      <TodoList appActions={appActions} apps={apps} />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
};
```

**app/actions/apps.ts**

```
export const getAppData = () => {
    let appKey = 'interpegasus';
    return (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
      dispatch(StatusActions.startAppLoading());
      debugger;
      apolloClient
        .query({
          query: gql`
            query getApp($appKey: String!) {
              getApp(id: $appKey) {
                id
                name
                domain
              }
            }
          `,
          variables: {
            appKey: appKey
          }
        })
        .then((result) => {
          debugger;
          if (result.data.apps.length > 0) {
            dispatch(populateAppData(result.data.apps[0]));
          }
          dispatch(StatusActions.endAppLoading());
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          dispatch(StatusActions.endAppLoading());
          console.log({
            error: error
          });
        });
    };
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put your `appActions.getAppData()` inside `useEffect` hooks like this

```
useEffect(()=>{

 appActions.getAppData()

},[])
```

check the official docs [Introducing Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)

Answer (score 1):

In `Main/index.tsx`, you are calling `appActions.getAppData();` which will lead you to `actions/apps.ts`. Here, you are doing `dispatch(StatusActions.startAppLoading());` which will update the state and re-render ``Main/index.tsx`. Then again you call getAppData() and the loop continues to lead to infinite loop.

Call the api only if not `loading`.

**Something like this:**

```js
  ...
  const { apps, loading } = useSelector((state: RootState) => {
    return {
      apps: state.apps,
      loading: state.loading // <----- replace with your actual name of your state 
    };
  });

  if(!loading){
    appActions.getAppData();
  }
  ...
```